# Why anything does not show the lines after 220 2.0.0 Start TLS?

Tags: php, ssl, smtp

Here is the code:

```
$fp = stream_socket_client("smtp.mail.yahoo.com:587", $errno, $errstr, 10);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, "EHLO my.hostname\r\n");
    echo fgets($fp, 1024).'<br>';
    echo fgets($fp, 1024).'<br>';
    echo fgets($fp, 1024).'<br>';
    echo fgets($fp, 1024).'<br>';
    echo fgets($fp, 1024).'<br>';
    echo fgets($fp, 1024).'<br>';

    fwrite($fp, "STARTTLS\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "EHLO my.hostname\r\n");

    echo fgets($fp, 1024).'<br>';
    echo fgets($fp, 101024).'<br>';
}
```

the problem is that when i run this in browser i just get these:

```
220 smtp.mail.yahoo.com ESMTP ready   
250-smtp.mail.yahoo.com   
250-PIPELINING   
250-SIZE 41697280   
250-8 BITMIME   
250 STARTTLS   
220 2.0.0 Start TLS
```

So why the lines after "220 2.0.0 Start TLS" does not show? is there any problem with the code or what?

just one more thing, instead of `fwrite($fp, "EHLO my.hostname\r\n");` in the last line, i used other commands like `QUIT` but the same result!!

Comment: "So why the lines after "220 2.0.0 Start TLS" does not show?" - You started TLS. If you need to test the connection, try `openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect smtp.mail.yahoo.com:587`. The browser can't give you anything useful because it does not understand the `STARTTLS` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you send STARTTLS, the communication goes into encrypted mode, which is why no further unencrypted commands work.  You probably don't want to be getting stuck into encrypting your message - if you just want to send a mail you can use PHPMailer

https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i think i got what i wanted to know ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rebuild existing functionality yourself please read the documentation or a library which already implements this and don't just guess and ask if it not works. SMTP is described in RFC 5321 and the behavior with STARTTLS in RFC3207.

Just a few hints: you need to do a TLS upgrade after you got the response to STARTTLS and before sending any other command. Also, there is no guarantee that the response to EHLO is exactly 5 lines.